# MySQL Cluster - SQL Node wont start - Failed to allocate nodeid

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

The 2 data nodes is now running. Hoever, SqlNode wont start.

config.ini

```
[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.177.132
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[ndbd]
hostname=192.168.177.133
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data

[mysqld]
hostname=192.168.177.131
```

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
ndb-connectstring=192.168.177.134
basedir=/usr/local/mysql

[mysql_cluster]
ndb-connectstring=192.168.177.134
```

I am getting this error...

```
[ndbd] INFO     -- Angel connected to '192.168.177.134:1186'
[ndbd] ERROR    -- Failed to allocate nodeid, error: 'Error: Could not alloc node id at 192.168.177.134 port 1186: Connection done from wrong host ip 192.168.177.131.'
```

Comment: were you able to figure out why ? I had the exact same problem...

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, you need to include an [ndb_mgmd] section in your config.ini file.

You then need to start the ndb_mgdm process, then your two ndbds and finally your mysqld.

I'd suggest starting with the instructions here... [Deploying MySQL Cluster over multiple hosts](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/deploying-mysql-cluster-over-multiple-hosts/)

You should also try setting the NodeId=x parameter for each of the nodes.

Comment: I have already included [ndb_mgmd] section in my config.ini file and start the ndb_mgdm

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed by Disabling my firewall in management node.

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your ndb_mgmd firewall open allow port 1186 to work (changing this port to another documented but not working)
second, try --reload or --initiate on starting ndb_mgmd, or this ndb_mgmd will load configuration from cache.